# How to handle Content-Diposition:attachment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I try to call a google URL to get stock information in my app.

The JavaScript code as below:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/finance/match?matchtype=matchall&q=msft";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: url
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

From the console log, the run result is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Google response header is:

```
Alternate-Protocol:80:quic
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="json.txt"; filename*=UTF-8''json.txt
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 24 Oct 2013 04:52:40 GMT
Expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:GSE
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

The response body is a well formatted JSON

```
{"matches":[{"t":"MSFT","n":"Microsoft Corporation","e":"NASDAQ","id":"358464"},{"t":"MSFT34","n":"MICROSOFT -DRN","e":"BVMF","id":"229763171687562"}]}
```

but the response is an attachment since the response header specifies `Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="json.txt"; filename*=UTF-8''json.txt`

How can I handle the Content-Disposition:attachment type response in JavaScript?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leoliaolei/8bMTn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Your best bet is probably to proxy the request from your own server, and strip away the content-disposition header.